# WatchPaths not working for file added in OSX

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

I am using MAC OSX 10.6.8.
I would like to apply a script that copy a backup file when I find there is a file named temp.txt.
Here is my plist in /Library/LaunchAgents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.lion.backupfile</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Users/lion/q_backup.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Users/lion/temp.txt</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I find the script only be excuted when file being removed or modified.
How could I excute the script when there is a file exist in the path?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such key in [launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html).
`WatchPaths` will work if any one of the listed paths are modified.

Comment: Hi Parag, so there is no way to detect a file be added in launchd? Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: PathState (KeepAlive) key is there but not for executing scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[`QueueDirectories`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-SW8) will run your script whenever there's a file in that directory.